# Combined overlap area question

Tags: area

I'm having a bit of trouble with this question:

Sue works in a rug shop. She as three rugs with a combined area of $200 m^2$.

She arranged the rugs so they overlap and cover a floor area of $140 m^2$.

The total floor area that is covered by exactly two layers of rugs is $24 m^2$.

What is the floor area that is covered by exactly three layers of rugs, in $m^2$?

The answer I get is $36$, and searching online that's what other people are getting too. However, the given answer is 18. How is that so? Thanks.

Comment: Use the inclusion exclusion principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *$200 m^2$* of rug have to be "used up".

A single layer will use up *$140 m^2$*, *$60 m^2$* carpet area left.

The 2-layer part will use up *60 - 24* = *$36 m^2$*

In the 3-layer part, **two** carpets are overlapping with the single layer,

thus part needing 3 layers = **$\frac{36}{2} = 18 m^2$**

Or if you **must** have algebra, let *x, 24, z be $m^2$* of single, double, triple layered portions, then

**x + 2*24 + 3z = 200 ... (i )**

**x + 24 + z = 140 ... (ii)**

Subtracting, **24 + 2z = 60**

**z = 18**